# Blazor BECanvasComponent render image not on page

Tags: c#, image, canvas, blazor, blazor-webassembly

## Current

I'm currently trying to create the proper version of an app in *Blazor WebAssembly* that I prototyped in Angular so I can share the code with the API and Mobile app.

For the Angular version, I am loading and rendering images with this:

```
this.imageObj = new Image();
this.imageObj.src = '/assets/ImageFile.jpg';
this.imageObj.addEventListener('load', () => this.drawScreen());
...(later)...
context.drawImage(this.imageObj, 0, 0, drawWidth, drawHeight, left, top, drawWidth, drawHeight);
```

## Problem

The issue is that even though the prototype is fixed, the proper app should render from a script. Which means the above image object can't be on a tag in the page because it isn't known at compile time.

I've got the Blazor app using a *BECanvas* to render to, but I can't create a C# object that represents an **img** tag that I can pass to *context.DrawImageAsync()*.

Everything I've looked up expects you to use a hidden *img* so you can have a **EntityReference**. But I can't define these in the page.

## Attempted Solutions

### Code

I've tried looking up what the code equivalent is for an *img* object to create and load. But I can't find anything.

### JsRuntime

I had the idea of creating the object in JS using *JsRuntime* and returning it. But I don't know how to get the returned object to be the right type.

### SkiaSharp

I think *SkiaSharp* works with Blazor. Should I just switch to that?

Comment: `But I can't define these in the page.` Can you explain more why you cannot define `img` on the page? You could simply control it with a simple if `@if (condition) { <img... }`.

Comment: Because the images are defined by a JSON config that is downloaded. So one config might reference three images, but one might reference twenty images.

So to put img tags on the page, I would have to use the bad programming pattern of having <img id="img01" hidden><img id="img02" hidden>' and have an upper limit of the count depending on how many placeholder tags I've added.

Comment: In that case, I think the best option is to continue to handle it in JavaScript like your example. You could pass a reference to the canvas to your JavaScript code. Blazor doesn't support passing object references from JavaScript to C# as far as I know.